# Calculate multiple moving calculations in one statement

Tags: r, tidyverse, quantmod, tidyquant

I want to calculate all moving averages in one statement rather than repeating myself. Is this possible using quantmod or does it require some clever use of tidyeval and/or purrr?

```
library(tidyquant)
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)

tibble(date = as.Date('2018-01-01') + days(1:100), 
       value = 100 + cumsum(rnorm(100))) %>% 
  tq_mutate(mutate_fun = rollapply, select = "value", width = 10, FUN = mean, col_rename = "rm10") %>% 
  tq_mutate(mutate_fun = rollapply, select = "value", width = 5, FUN = mean, col_rename = "rm5") %>% 
  gather(series, value, -date) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, color = series)) + 
     geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table`'s new `frollmean()`-function
`data.table` v1.12.0 or higher required.

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table( date = as.Date('2018-01-01') + days(1:100), 
            value = 100 + cumsum(rnorm(100)))
```

**code**

```
#set windwos you want to roll on
windows <- c(5,10)
#create a rm+window column for each roll
dt[, ( paste0( "rm", windows ) ) := lapply( windows, function(x) frollmean( value, x)) ]
```

**output**

```
head( dt, 15 )
#           date     value      rm5     rm10
#  1: 2018-01-02  99.43952       NA       NA
#  2: 2018-01-03  99.20935       NA       NA
#  3: 2018-01-04 100.76806       NA       NA
#  4: 2018-01-05 100.83856       NA       NA
#  5: 2018-01-06 100.96785 100.2447       NA
#  6: 2018-01-07 102.68292 100.8933       NA
#  7: 2018-01-08 103.14383 101.6802       NA
#  8: 2018-01-09 101.87877 101.9024       NA
#  9: 2018-01-10 101.19192 101.9731       NA
# 10: 2018-01-11 100.74626 101.9287 101.0867
# 11: 2018-01-12 101.97034 101.7862 101.3398
# 12: 2018-01-13 102.33015 101.6235 101.6519
# 13: 2018-01-14 102.73092 101.7939 101.8482
# 14: 2018-01-15 102.84161 102.1239 102.0485
# 15: 2018-01-16 102.28577 102.4318 102.1802
```

**plot**

```
#plot molten data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( data = melt(dt, id.vars = c("date") ), 
        aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

## update - grouped data

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
#changed the sample data a bit, to get different values for grp=1 and grp=2
dt <- data.table(grp = rep(1:2, each = 100), date = rep(as.Date('2018-01-01') + days(1:100), 2), value = 100 + cumsum(rnorm(200)))
dt[, ( paste0( "rm", windows ) ) := lapply( windows, function(x) frollmean( value, x)), by = "grp" ]
ggplot( data = melt(dt, id.vars = c("date", "grp") ), 
        aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~grp, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: very nice, but what if we have a grouping variable in dt?

dt <- data.table(grp = rep(1:2, each = 100),
                         data = rep(as.Date('2018-01-01') + days(1:100), 2),
                          value = rep(100 + cumsum(rnorm(100)), 2))

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought the big warning error was an error when i tried it myself.

Comment: @Rickard what warning? I updated the code above a (tiny) bit, there was an error in an argument in the follmean()-function. change `dt$value` to `value`.. I do not get any warnings (except the plotting of NA's in the ggplot, which makes perfect sense).

Comment: RHS 1 is length 200 (greater than the size(100) of group 1). The last 100 element(s) will be discarded. RHS 2 is length .... RHS <number of rolling windows>

the warning was caused by using frollmean(dt$value, x) instead of frollmean(value, x)

Comment: Ok thanks, so it is fixed now i guess. No warnings anymore using the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

In this example I use the AAPL adjusted close price downloaded using the `getSymbols` function from `quantmod`

lets say you want the SMAs with the following lengths:

```
smaLength = c(30,35,40,46,53,61,70,81,93)
```

Now create the SMA like so:

```
lapply(smaLength,function(x) SMA(AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted,x)) %>% do.call(cbind,.) %>% tail()
```

result:

```
                SMA    SMA.1    SMA.2    SMA.3    SMA.4    SMA.5    SMA.6    SMA.7    SMA.8
2019-03-04 167.3703 165.2570 163.3706 162.1362 161.5904 162.9735 164.7770 169.3341 175.4143
2019-03-05 168.0162 165.9396 164.0682 162.5499 161.7934 162.8342 164.6408 168.9595 174.9418
2019-03-06 168.7454 166.6585 164.7488 162.9638 162.0062 162.8110 164.6165 168.6446 174.5135
2019-03-07 169.3866 167.2323 165.3086 163.3320 162.1409 162.7868 164.5661 168.2780 174.0284
2019-03-08 170.0820 167.7646 165.8150 163.6764 162.3807 162.8711 164.5855 167.8407 173.5334
2019-03-11 170.8092 168.4419 166.4589 164.1471 162.8097 163.0354 164.6573 167.4864 173.0806
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the input and then lapply over the widths creating a rollmean for each one merging them together.  Finally plot it.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

set.seed(123)
w <- c(1, 5, 10)
zoo(100 * cumsum(rnorm(100)), as.Date("2018-01-01") + 1:100) %>%
  lapply(w, rollmeanr, x = .) %>%
  do.call("merge", .) %>%
  setNames(w) %>%
  autoplot(facet = NULL)
```

[image: screenshot]